# Add two values of different textField to fill another textField on multiple lines

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

Whenever I input the value of quantity and unit cost for each line, I want to automatically display the multiplied result into the total cost field.

I wrote the jquery script below trying to figure out how to go about it but couldn't get it working

```
$('.unit, .quantity').on('change', function() {
           // var quantity = $('#expenseslist-quantity').val();
           // var unit = $('#expenseslist-unit_cost').val();
           var total = 0;
            $('.quantity, .unit').each(function(){
                total = quantity * unit ;
            });
            $('#expenseslist-total_cost').val(total);
        });
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Do $(this).val() in each function ....

Comment: Can you update your html code. Because I want to check whether you are setting your value or the html. Please update your html code

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATED ANSWER:

As per your recent information, I made required changes to the code.

PS: For this, you have to make some changes on your HTML too and have to insert `data-` attributes on them.

For Unit input: `data-type="unit" data-field="field_{1}"`

For Quantity input: `data-type="qty" data-field="field_{1}"`

For the output input area: `data-field-count="field_{1}"`

After that, try out this code:

```
$('.unit, .quantity').on('keyup', function() {
let fieldType = $(this).data('type'),
        fieldCount = $(this).data('field'),
        intOne = $(this).val(),
        intTwo = 1

    if (fieldType == 'qty') {
        intTwo = $('input[data-type=qty]').val()
    } else {
        intTwo = $('input[data-type=unit]').val()
    }

    let total = intOne * intTwo

    $('input[data-field-count='+ fieldCount +']').val(total);
});
```

### OLD ANSWER:

Since your query is pretty vague, this is what I understood from it:

```
$('.unit, .quantity').on('keyup', function() {
    let qty = $('#expenseslist-quantity').val(),
        unit = $('#expenseslist-unit_cost').val()

    let total = unit * qty

    $('#expenseslist-total_cost').val(total);
});
```

I don't know why you are using the `each` loop. Are there more than one *unit* and  *quantity* fields?

Comment: Yes there are more than unit and quantity fields and I also attached the look of the form to my first post.

Answer (score 0):

> Try to learn how to implement dynamic element

```js
$('.unit, .quantity').on('change', function(event) {
 var total1 = 0;
             var total2 = 0;
            var quantity1 = $('#expenseslist-quantity1').val();
            var unit1 = $('#expenseslist-unit_cost1').val();
            
            total1 = quantity1 * unit1 ;
           
            
         $('#expenseslist-total_cost1').val(total1);
            var quantity2 = $('#expenseslist-quantity2').val();
            var unit2 = $('#expenseslist-unit_cost2').val();
            total2 = quantity2 * unit2 ;
         $('#expenseslist-total_cost2').val(total2);
         
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
 <tr class="primary">
  <td width="170">
   <div class="form-group field-expenseslist-item_id">


    <select id="expenseslist-item_id" class="form-control" name="ExpensesList[item_id][]" required="">
     <option value="">Select an Item</option>
     <option value="1">Vehicle General Repairs And Maintenance</option>
     <option value="2">Transportation Cost</option>
    </select>

    <div class="help-block"></div>

   </div> 
  </td>        

  <td width="450"><div class="form-group field-expenseslist-request_explanation">


   <textarea id="expenseslist-request_explanation" class="form-control" name="ExpensesList[request_explanation][]" rows="2" required=""></textarea>

   <div class="help-block"></div>

  </div>      
 </td>
 <td width="80"><div class="form-group field-expenseslist-quantity">


  <input type="number" id="expenseslist-quantity1" class="form-control quantity" name="ExpensesList[quantity][]" value="0" required="">

  <div class="help-block"></div>

 </div> 
</td>
<td width="130"><div class="form-group field-expenseslist-unit_cost">


 <input type="number" id="expenseslist-unit_cost1" class="form-control unit" name="ExpensesList[unit_cost][]" value="0" required="">

 <div class="help-block"></div>

</div> 
</td>
<td width="150"><div class="form-group field-expenseslist-total_cost">


 <input type="text" id="expenseslist-total_cost1" class="form-control total" name="ExpensesList[total_cost][]" value="0" readonly="readonly" required="">

 <div class="help-block"></div>

</div>       
</td>
<!--  <td>
<button>Add</button>
</td> -->
</tr>
<tr class="primary">
 <td width="170">
  <div class="form-group field-expenseslist-item_id">


   <select id="expenseslist-item_id" class="form-control" name="ExpensesList[item_id][]" required="">
    <option value="">Select an Item</option>
    <option value="1">Vehicle General Repairs And Maintenance</option>
    <option value="2">Transportation Cost</option>
   </select>

   <div class="help-block"></div>

  </div> 
 </td>        

 <td width="450"><div class="form-group field-expenseslist-request_explanation">


  <textarea id="expenseslist-request_explanation" class="form-control" name="ExpensesList[request_explanation][]" rows="2" required=""></textarea>

  <div class="help-block"></div>

 </div>      
</td>
<td width="80"><div class="form-group field-expenseslist-quantity">


 <input type="number" id="expenseslist-quantity2" class="form-control quantity" name="ExpensesList[quantity][]" value="0" required="">

 <div class="help-block"></div>

</div> 
</td>
<td width="130"><div class="form-group field-expenseslist-unit_cost">


 <input type="number" id="expenseslist-unit_cost2" class="form-control unit" name="ExpensesList[unit_cost][]" value="0" required="">

 <div class="help-block"></div>

</div> 
</td>
<td width="150"><div class="form-group field-expenseslist-total_cost">


 <input type="text" id="expenseslist-total_cost2" class="form-control total" name="ExpensesList[total_cost][]" value="0" readonly="readonly" required="">

 <div class="help-block"></div>

</div>       
</td>
<!--  <td>
<button>Add</button>
</td> -->
<td><div class="btn btn-sm btn-danger rmv">Delete</div></td></tr></tbody>
```